# pthread_mutex_unlock not atomic

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, pthreads

I've the following source code (adapted from my original code):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

#include "pthread.h"

#define MAX_ENTRY_COUNT 4  

int  entries = 0;  
bool start = false;

bool send_active = false;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  
pthread_cond_t condNotEmpty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  
pthread_cond_t condNotFull = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;  

void send()
{ 
    for (;;) {
        if (!start)
            continue;
        start = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) { 
            send_active = true;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); 
            while(entries == MAX_ENTRY_COUNT) 
                pthread_cond_wait(&condNotFull, &mutex);      
            entries++; 
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&condNotEmpty); 
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

            send_active = false;
        }
    }
} 

void receive(){ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i){ 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
        while(entries == 0) 
            pthread_cond_wait(&condNotEmpty, &mutex); 
        entries--;  
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&condNotFull);  
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    } 

    if (send_active)
        printf("x");
} 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pthread_t s; 

    pthread_create(&s, NULL, (void *(*)(void*))send, NULL);  

    for (;;) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&condNotEmpty, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&condNotFull, NULL);

        start = true;

        receive();

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        mutex = NULL;
        pthread_cond_destroy(&condNotEmpty);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&condNotFull);
        condNotEmpty = NULL;
        condNotFull = NULL;

        printf(".");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is like follows: from time to time the last unlock in the send function is not finished before the receive method continues. In my original code the mutexes are located in an objects which are deleted after doing the job. If the send method has not finished with the last unlock then the mutexes are invalid and my program causes failures in unlock.

The behavior can be easily reproduced by running the program: each time the "x" is diplayed the receive method has nearly finished and the send method "hangs" in the unlock call.

I've compiled with VS2008 and VS2010 - both results are same.

pthread_mutex_unlock is not atomic, this would solve the problem. How can I solve this issue? Any comments are welcome...

Best regards

Michael

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but don't you need to wait for the send thread to terminate (`pthread_join(s, NULL);`) before you attempt to destroy the mutex that it relies on?

Comment: Also you don't need to / shouldn't initialize a mutex both with the static initializer `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and a call to `pthread_mutex_init`.  (Attempting to initialize an already initialized mutex results in undefined behavior.)

Comment: The send thread is a thread that never ends in my application (it's an I/O thread in fact).

Comment: I understood the phtread mutex lock mechanism in the following way:

Comment: I'm guessing this might really be a bug. `pthread_mutex_unlock` is not allowed to access any part of the mutex structure after it's unlocked because of race conditions like what you seem to be describing, but the windows implementation may be broken...

Comment: I understood the phtread mutex lock mechanism in the following way: the lock in the receive function is released after finishing the unlock in the send function.

Comment: You are updating the `send_active` variable outside holding the mutex. This is wrong. move both updates inside the section where you hold the mutex.

Comment: OK, I think I see now. Why are you destroying an reinitializing the mutex that the send function? This is no other mutex protection on the `start` variable. Why not initialize the mutex variable once and use it throughout the lifetime of the program?

Comment: I've a lot of receivers in my application. They are created on the heap and destroyed after finishing. Each receiver has it's own mutexes and conditions.

Comment: But in this code, the lifetime of the mutex should clearly last as long as either _the_ sender or _a_ receiver is alive because both of these functions use it. It makes no sense to destroy and recreate it more frequently than is actually needed.

Comment: Are you using pthreads from http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ or some other library (I'm unaware of one that comes with the Windows SDK or Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 1):

Your printf("x") is a textbook race condition example.

After pthread_mutex_unlock() OS is free to not schedule this thread for any amount of time: ticks, seconds or days. You can't assume that send_active will be "falsified" in time.

Comment: the printf race condition is clear. But: the last unlock in the inner for loop  of my send function doesn't return sometimes before the receive function continues. That's my problem...

Comment: @michael: could you show code that mode clearly shows why it's a problem if you're not after the race condition on `send_active`?

Comment: @michael It is not guaranteed that pthread_mutex_unlock() will really return right after unlocking. Obviously there is some syscall inside, before "return" statement and thread scheduling occurs on syscall return. Thread can stuck in kernel forever, if some higher priority thread/process requires CPU time. You can hardly tell a difference between being stuck in kernel or single instruction after CALL pthread_mutex_unlock()

Comment: @Michael Burr: I got errors from pthread_mutex_unlock (mutex handle invalid) in send function because the object holding the mutex was freed during the meantime (receive and all subsequent work was done). These errors are really seldom: sometimes after 5.000 receives, sometimes after 50.000...

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_mutex_unlock()` must by definition release the mutex before it returns.  The instant the mutex is released, another thread that's contending for the mutex could be scheduled.  Note that even if `pthread_mutex_unlock()` could arrange to not release the mutex until just after it returned (what I think you mean by it being atomic), there would still be an equivalent race condition to whatever you're seeing now (it's not clear to me what race you're seeing since a comment indicates that ou're not realy interested in the race condition of accessing `send_active` to control the `printf()` call).

In that case the other thread could be scheduled 'between-the-lines' of the `pthread_mutex_unlock()` and the following statement/expression in the function that called it - you'd have the same race condition.

Comment: I checked my code with the debugger and in fact the pthread_mutex_unlock was not returned. The thread stopped at the SetEvent call in pthread_mutex_unlock.

Comment: send_active and printf are only helpers for debugging. I set a breakpoint on the printf and this put me to the line SetEvent in pthread_mutex_unlock.

Comment: I see - that sounds like a bug in the pthread library (as R.. mentioned in a comment). What pthread library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some speculation on what might be happening. A couple caveats on this analysis:

- this is based on the assumption that you're using the Win32 pthreads package from http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/
- this is based only on a pretty brief examination of the pthreads source on that site and the information in the question and comments here - I have not had an opportunity to actually try to run/debug any of the code.

When `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is called, it decrements a lock count, and if that lock count drops to zero, the Win32 `SetEvent()` API is called on an associated event object to let any threads waiting on the mutex to be unblocked.  Pretty standard stuff.

Here's where the speculation comes in.  Lets say that `SetEvent()` has been called to unblock thread(s) waiting on the mutex, and it signals the event associated with the handle it was given (as it should).  However, before the `SetEvent()` function does anything else, another thread starts running and closes the event object handle that that particular `SetEvent()` was called with (by calling `pthread_mutex_destroy()`).

Now the `SetEvent()` call in progress has a handle value that's no longer valid.  I can't think of a particular reason that `SetEvent()` would do anything with that handle after it's signaled the event, but maybe it does (I could also imagine someone making a reasonable argument that `SetEvent()` should be able to expect that the event object handle remain valid for the duration of the API call).

If this is what's happening to you (and that's a *big* if), I'm not sure if there's an easy fix. I think that the pthreads library would have to have changes made so that it duplicated the event handle before calling `SetEvent()` then close that duplicate when the `SetEvent()` call returned. That way the handle would remain valid even if the 'main' handle were closed by another thread. I'm guessing it would have to do this in a number of places. This could be implemented by replacing the affected Win32 API calls with calls to wrapper functions that perform the "duplicate handle/call API/close duplicate" sequence.

It might not be unreasonable for you to try to make this change for the `SetEvent()` call in `pthread_mutex_unlock()` and see if it solves (or at least improves) your particular problem. If so, you may want to contact the maintainer of the library to see if a more comprehensive fix might be arranged somehow (be prepared - you may be asked to do a significant part of the work).

Out of curiosity, in your debugging of the state of the thread that hangs in `pthread_mutex_unlock()`/`SetEvent()`, do you have any information on exactly whats happening?  What `SetEvent()` is waiting for? (the cdb debugger that's in the Debugging Tools for Windows package might be able to give you more information about this than the Visual Studio debugger).

Also, note the following comment in the source for `pthread_mutex_destroy()` which seems related (but different) than your particular problem:

```
/*
 * FIXME!!!
 * The mutex isn't held by another thread but we could still
 * be too late invalidating the mutex below since another thread
 * may already have entered mutex_lock and the check for a valid
 * *mutex != NULL.
 *
 * Note that this would be an unusual situation because it is not
 * common that mutexes are destroyed while they are still in
 * use by other threads.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael, thank you for your investigation and comments!

The code I'm using is from http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/.

The situation described by you in the third and fourth paragraph is exactly what's happening.

I've checked some solutions and a simple one seems to work for me: I waiting till the send function (and SetEvent) has finished. All my tests with this solution were successful till now. I'm going to do a larger test over the weekend.